# Regex utf-8 arabic

Tags: regex, .htaccess, utf-8

i have 404 NOT FOUND when i have utf-8 (arabic) in my slug url

there is my code in php file:

```
'slug' => '[A-Za-z0-9\_-]+'
```

and this in htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

#Charset
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#Protect - DOS
LimitRequestBody 10000000

#Index Protect
Options All -Indexes

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

when i have link like : www.test.com/تست 
server return 404 not found and when i use

```
'slug' => '[ا-یa-zA-Z0-9\-_]+'
```

and the same for htaccess i have loop redirection!

ا-یa-zآ-یA-Z

Comment: This looks like just htaccess, not preg_match or php. Is that correct or is there more code?

Comment: i have updated post ! full htaccess code !

Comment: preg_match is a PHP function using a regular expression for matching a string, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/preg-match/info. This looks like an issue with regexs in your htaccess file. Where is `'slug' => '[ا-یa-zA-Z0-9\-_]+'`?

Comment: You might want to try `\u0600-\u06FF` as range.

Comment: Instead of `[ا-یa-zA-Z0-9\-_]+` - `[\u0600-\u06FFa-zA-Z0-9\-_]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the character class part of the regex to `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Pd}_]`

`\p{L}` matches anything unicode that qualifies as a Letter but not underscores

`\p{N}` matches anything that looks like a number

`\p{Pd}` is Punctuation Dash which includes hyphen.

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for more on Unicode Regular Expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `([^/]+)` , it works!
This pattern allows everything that is not a slash.

Comment: Would you like to augment your code-only answer with an explanation?

Comment: if it success you can combine or do custom regex for slashes... :)